VB unable to wrap password which contains semi colon in quotes - Data source name not found and no default driver specified
I am using a program called UFT One which I beleive uses VB Script for it functions
I have a function which connects to an Oracle Database using ODBC in Windows (which works) however since they just changed the password and put a semi colon in it, I can not get the password to work properly wrapping it around any sort of quotes as advised when I searched for the issue
When I do that, I am getting the error:
"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"
here is my original connection string:
getConnectionString = "DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient19Home1_32bit};DBQ=<IP_ADDRESS>:<PORT>/<SID>;Trusted_Connection=Yes;UID=<USERNAME>;Password=<PASSWORD>;Connection Timeout=600"
So when they changed the password that has a semicolon: ie XXxxxXXXX;XXX I got a username/password incorrect error as the password was truncated at the ; in the password
I have tried the following suggestions:
Password=""XXxxxXXXX;XXX"";Connection Timeout=600"
Password='XXxxxXXXX;XXX';Connection Timeout=600"
Password={XXxxxXXXX;XXX};Connection Timeout=600"
Password=XXxxxXXXX%x3BXXX";Connection Timeout=600"
the last one just gets incorrect password as it's passing through %x#B instead of ; but all the others gets me the Data source error so it seems it doesnt like the double quoting, single quoting, {} and doing this stuffs up the rest of the connection string
When I debug the code I see for the double quotes it does pass the connection string through as just one pair of double quotes ie
getConnectionString = "DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient19Home1_32bit};DBQ=<IP_ADDRESS>:<PORT>/<SID>;Trusted_Connection=Yes;UID=<USERNAME>;Password="XXxxxXXXX;XXX";Connection Timeout=600"
Tried all wrapping passwords in "", ', `, {}

Related answer here. If those quoting rules don't work for you then you're almost certainly encountering a bug in the ODBC driver or one of the other components in the stack.

@GordThompson According to the question Password={XXxxxXXXX;XXX}; is not working either despite it should work.

Method ADODB.Connection.Open is overloaded, try to open the connection like this:
conString = "DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient19Home1_32bit};DBQ=<IP_ADDRESS>:<PORT>/<SID>;Trusted_Connection=Yes;Connection Timeout=600"

connection.Open conString, <USERNAME>, <PASSWORD>


Thanks unfortunately that yields me the same error :(

Did you remove the password from connection string?

Yes removed the password from the connection string
Tested the new way with a password without a semi colon and it works just says password is wrong. But as soon as I put the semi colon in, It is getting the error so I guess it sees the format of the connection string being incorrect now
Happening the same on 3 different machines so it must be an issue with ODBC or could be a UFT One Issue
thankfully we got them to change the password now and take the semi colon out so Im good to go but still cant work out why it wouldnt work with the password with semi colon
